# Using different tables for different kind of datatypes in mysql

Tags: mysql, database-design, relational-database, database-schema, sqldatatypes

I'm creating a database for a member administration. We've got elements (users) and these users have properties (for instance, surname, last name, date of birth). Now, the names are text, but the date of birth is a date, so i want to store this in a column with datatype "date". Because the properties of the users may differ, i want a table with elements, a table with properties and a table that links the two together. However, to be able to use different kind of datatypes, for each datatype i would have to create a different table. You would get something like this:

```
Table: Users
------------
user
1
2

table: properties
---------------------------------
property  propertyName   datatype
1         surname        text
2         lastname       text
3         date of birth  date

Table: PropertiesString
---------------------------
property   value
1          John
2          Tim
3          Smith
4          Jones

Table: PropertiesDate
-------------------------
property   value
1          04-11-1966
2          07-08-1971

table: userPropertiesLinked
-----------------------------
user   property propertyValue
1      1        1
1      2        3
2      1        2
2      2        4
2      3        1
1      3        2
```

This, put together, shows us that we have 2 users, John Smith (04-11-1966) and Tim Jones (07-08-1971).

My question is: is this the best way to go at it? The way this DB is setup is very searchfriendly, people can have multiple properties, properties aren't stored twice, etc. The problem i'm running into, is the fact that "property" 1 in one table is John, and in the other 04-11-1966. Is there a way to make these values unique and to auto increment, even though they are in different tables? Is there a way to put them into one table, without risking double information or empty cells?

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Have you ever done this before? If not, read up on foreign keys.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can consider the foreign key to connect with two tabls but the same values, like this:

```
constraint PropertiesString_fk foreign key (value) references  PropertiesDate(or other table) value.
```

As for auto increment, you can think like this:

```
ALTER TABLE tablename DROP id;
ALTER TABLE tablename ADD id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT FIRST
```

As how to put them into one table,  you can use the command "select" and "distinct"